# Html form for emails. Emails go to text or word file on an ipad

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

I am trying to have users use an HTML form to input their email addresses but I would like the addresses to go to a word doc or notepad or a text file on the iPad pro they are entering this all on.

I'm trying to figure out the best method to do this as I'm not using a hosted server.

So far this is what I've been using in my HTML file:

```
<form action="" method="post>
Name:
<input type="text" name="name">
Email:
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Can you tell me if I need to incorporate PHP or tell me how to do that?  I've tried using POST but kept getting 'Post method not allowed' and if I tried to use GET, I would get an internal server error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "or a text file on the iPad pro they are entering this all on"… "I'm not using a hosted server". I'm pretty confused about what you're trying to accomplish. Please read [ask] and make sure you include enough context.

Comment: you would have to run php and a webserver on the ipad, so there are better options than even going down this road. just look in the ipad store for 'form' or 'survey' apps ie http://ipadformmaker.com/

Comment: _"kept getting 'Post method not allowed'"_ - who is sayng that? Youre web (apache?) server? _"get an internal server error"_ - what error?

Comment: Hi Chris, here's a better explanation: Users will be accessing an iPad that has an HTML/CSS/Javascript app on it that is using a form for them to input their email on. I'd like those emails to then go to a file on the same iPad (essentially collecting that data in another file, it can be in a Word doc for example).  Everything is local. Is that a little clearer?

Comment: it's clearer, but I'm afraid that's not (so easily) possible. You cannot acces local filesystem via php or javascript (well, not directly), as this would be a major security issue. Take @smith's comment.

Comment: That's fine.  I just wanted to see what direction I should start so this was helpful.